# Starting import from CSV from row 2 using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, import-from-csv

I'm new to VBA and therefore need some help. I'm trying to import data from a CSV file using a method where I can chose the csv of a list using the following piece of code:

```
Private Sub commandbuttonimport_click()



Dim fd              As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .Filters.Clear
    .Title = "Select a CSV File"
    .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    Dim sfile       As String
    If .Show = True Then
        sfile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
End With

'import csv from filedialog
If sfile <> "" Then
    Open sfile For Input As #1
    row_number = 1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")
        Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(0)
        Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(1)
        Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(2)
        row_number = row_number + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
    End If
    
End Sub
```

But the thing is, I would only like to import the data from the chosen csv file starting from row 2 and skip the first one. If I manually delete the first row from the CSV file (which contains the headers) and then use the code above everything works, but if the headers remain no luck.

Help would be appreciated as I'm kinda stuck right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

```
'import csv from filedialog
Dim LineItems() As String
Dim LineFromFile As String
Dim line_number As Long
Dim row_number As Long

line_number = 1
row_number = 1
Open sfile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        If line_number > 1 Then
            LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")
            Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(0)
            Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(1)
            Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(2)
            row_number = row_number + 1
        End If
        line_number = line_number + 1
    Loop
Close #1
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, it looks like a line feed (vbLf) is used as the end of line marker.  Assuming that this is the case, you'll need to change your code to the following...

```
'import csv from filedialog
Dim DataFromFile As String
Dim LinesFromData() As String
Dim LineItems() As String
Dim row_number As Long
Open sfile For Input As #1
    DataFromFile = Input(LOF(1), 1) ' get contents from entire file
    LinesFromData = Split(DataFromFile, vbLf) ' split data into separate lines assuming line feed as end of file marker
    For row_number = LBound(LinesFromData) + 1 To UBound(LinesFromData) ' +1 to start with second line of data
        LineItems = Split(LinesFromData(row_number), ";") ' split the line into separate items
        If UBound(LineItems) <> -1 Then
            Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = LineItems
        End If
    Next row_number
Close #1
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it just returns no observations. 
`If sfile <> "" Then
    Open sfile For Input As #1
    line_number = 1
    row_number = 1
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    Do Until EOF(1)
        If line_number > 1 Then
            LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ";")
            Application.Range("FC_Range_Final").Cells(row_number, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = LineItems
            row_number = row_number + 1
        End If
        line_number = line_number + 1
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    Loop
    Close #1
End If

End Sub`

Comment: See my post, which has been edited to include the full, amended macro.

Comment: This is strange indeed. I tried running the code and it didn't work for the csv where the headers are still there but it worked for the file where I had removed them i.e. starting a line further down. The header looks like this: begin [Europe/Berlin];end [Europe/Berlin];Deutschland [kW]. Could that mess something up?

Comment: Sadly not. Maybe it's just not feasible this way.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible for the code to delete the first row of the csv file it opens, before extracting the data?

Comment: Try stepping through each line of code using the F8 key, and each time it executes the line `Line Input #1, LineFromFile` move your cursor over the variable `LineFromFile` to see the line that was input.  Does it return your expected results?  Maybe there's an extra line break of some sort?  If so, maybe you'll need to start from the 3rd row (ie. `If line_number > 2 Then`) ?

Comment: When I run through with F8 it prompts me with choosing a file around If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub. Then I choose a file and then it looks like it stops or at least when I press F8 it goes back to the top. I tried starting from line_number > 2 but that did not work either.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at `Line Input #1, LineFromFile`, and then run it.  After it prompts you to select a file and you click OK, it will stop at that line.  Then step through each line using F8 and see what `LineFromFile` gets assigned each time.

Comment: It seems that the first row of the csv is being chosen although i don't understand why. So it says LineFromFile = begin [Europe/Berlin];end [Europe/Berlin];Deutschland [kW] when i hover the cursor over the variable.

Comment: The first row will be assigned to `LineFromFile`, but it shouldn't be written to your worksheet since you have `If line_number > 1 Then`.

Comment: It doesn't actually assign it to my worksheet either so that's working, but it then seems it doesn't loop and catch all the rows beneath the header either.

Comment: So are you saying that when you run the macro, nothing gets written to your worksheet?

Comment: You said that your original code worked, except that it included the header row.  If that's the case, my code should work as well, except that it excludes the header row.  Are you using the same csv file?  Or are you now testing the code using a different file?  If you're using a different file, maybe it uses vbLf (line feed) to mark the end of line, instead of vbCrLf (carriage return + line feed).  If so, you'll need to change your code accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. My code only works when i remove the:  begin [Europe/Berlin];end [Europe/Berlin];Deutschland [kW] header from the csv I'm trying to import from. If I leave this in the file i want to import from i only get " begin [Europe/Berlin];end [Europe/Berlin];Deutschland [kW] " using my original code and nothing using your suggestion. If I on the other hand delete the first row from the csv file i.e. the header I get all the observations I want.